# Does bootstrap.js include event-handling logic? if so how does the browser know?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Take for example this pseudo-class

```
p: hover {
  background-color: blue
}
```

So when the browser parses HTML, it adds "hover" event listener to the paragraph element. It also creates a JavaScript event handler object to color the background of the paragraph to blue.

When the cursor hovers over the paragraph element, the event listener releases an event object - "hover event".

This event object goes to the event handler object. The browser sends this JavaScript event handler object to the JavaScript engine, which interprets this event handler object.

Browser then identifies the element to modify and modifies its property - background-color.

So how does bootstrap.js work?

Does this file define the event-handling logic when events are released? if yes how the browser that event-handling logic is in bootstrap.js?

Comment: bootstrap.js script will run in the page that is loaded in the browser - so that will register all the event handling hooks...